# Counting/grouping datapoints: for-loop or list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I’m trying to count a number of integer data points within 1000’s groups.

Let’s assume we have 10,000 data points in the range 0..999999:

```
import random
random.seed(123456) # generate a reproducable sequence

# make 10000 numbers in range 0..99999
maxn = 99999
numbers = [random.randint(0,maxn) for i in range(10000)]
```

Now which variant would be the "better" way to generate a list containing the counted number of data points within each 1000’s group?

"Better" can mean one of the following (please elaborate):

- better performance
- more pythonic
- better readable after 6 months …

**Variant 1:**

```
# generate a zero-initialized "array" to hold the counts per 1000's block
blocks1 = [0 for i in range(maxn/1000 +1)] # init 1D "array"

for num in numbers:
    blocks1[num / 1000] += 1 # int divide by 1000 gives index

print blocks1[1] # show how many in range 1000..1999
```

**Variant 2:**

```
# Use a really wild list comprehension:
blocks2 = [len(filter(lambda num: num/1000 == i, numbers))
    for i in range(maxn/1000+1)]

print blocks2[1] # show how many in range 1000..1999
```

Thanks for helping me doing stuff better in Python! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to count things, the most Pythonic answer is a `Counter`, a type of `dict` specialized for counting.

```py
from collections import Counter

Counter(n // 1000 for n in numbers)
```

Results in something like:

```py
Counter({0: 87,
         1: 113,
         2: 117,
         3: 99,
         4: 114,
         ...
```

Where the keys are the number of thousands in each "band" or group. So key 0 records values 0-999, 1 from 1000-1999, and so on.

But you can do this more neatly, too. First define a function (in this case, a one-line lambda function) that maps values into band names. Then construct a `Counter` across a generalized generator expression:

```py
bandof = lambda x, b=1000: '{}-{}'.format(x//b*b, (x//b+1)*b-1)
Counter(bandof(n) for n in numbers)
```

That yields something like:

```py
Counter({'0-999': 87,
         '1000-1999': 113,
         '10000-10999': 102,
         '11000-11999': 114,
         '12000-12999': 113,
         ...
```

The key ordering is different, and the keys are more symbolic, directly stating the range they represent, rather than making you translate indices to value ranges in your head.

A nice thing about generalizing like this is that any time you want to change the band size, it's trivial. E.g. for band size 2000:

```py
Counter(bandof(n, 2000) for n in numbers)
```

Yields:

```py
Counter({'0-1999': 200,
         '10000-11999': 216,
         '12000-13999': 235,
         '14000-15999': 186,
         '16000-17999': 188,
         ...
```

Pick band size 100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000, or whatever you like. It's not restricted to nice round numbers, either. If you want a band size of 391, that works too.

One final trick: While string keys are attractive for printing purposes, they can be less convenient for sorting, and for other kinds of further processing. So instead of formatting the group name into a string, it's often convenient to use a `tuple`:

```py
bandtuple = lambda x, b=1000: (x//b*b, (x//b+1)*b-1)
```

You call this categorizer function as before. Let's get wild and crazy and do it with an unusual band size:

```py
Counter(bandtuple(n, 3924) for n in numbers)
```

That yields something like:

```py
Counter({(0, 3923): 411,
         (3924, 7847): 386,
         (7848, 11771): 403,
         (11772, 15695): 417,
         (15696, 19619): 396,
         ...
```

Now the band start and stop values are still clear, but they're also immediately usable as data, too.

**NOTE**: The band start and stop values given here are inclusive / closed intervals. That works great for a lot of uses, but is ever so slightly but critically different from the half-open ranges commonly returned by Python's `range()` function / generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint at `collections` and `Counter`. I guess this is a module well worth checking out. I think I’ll follow your suggested route using `Counter` and have it return tuple/value pairs. Thanks for your time and the great explanation! Answer accepted :-)